# Are all clip planes used to determine rendered space in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I'm working with some legacy software that uses the fixed function rendering pipeline of openGL.

Clip boxes require a minimum of 6 planes to specify the region within which geometry is rendered. The specification indicates that I can define more such planes if necessary depending on number of available clip planes. In such cases, I imagine that the region specified by all the clip planes is used to determine the "display region". Is this correct?

Further, would it be possible to enable and disable these clipping planes for certain geometries only? The spec indicates that the clipping planes apply to all geometries but my colleague insists otherwise (without substantiation)

Comment: Can you show your code where clipping planes are used? I'm not sure this is OpenGL specific in any particular way. Sounds like you're talking about ["frustum culling"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum) in a more general sense.

Comment: @tadman Yes and no. The standard frustrum culling based on the viewmatrix is something we already do. Within our application, we allow "extra" clip planes to zero in on the geometry we are interested in. The glClipPlane commands are used for this. What I see is that the clip planes are enabled at the start of the frame and disabled at the end of the frame, as needed. I was wondering whether glEnable.glDisable could be used to control what gets clipped

Comment: @KaiBurjack What you've written is exactly what I was asking! Do you perhaps know what happens internally in this case? Are these clipping planes paired with the corresponding draw calls to perform the discard/retain check post rasterization?

Comment: @tadman Sadly, I don't have access to that portion of the code. I'm doing this based on the opengl command stream that I see using interception software (glIntercept, renderdoc, etc.).

Comment: If it's culled before it hits the OpenGL pipeline you might not even see the calls in the first place if you're stuck inspecting the OpenGL command stream.

Comment: " The spec indicates that the clipping planes apply to all geometries but my colleague insists otherwise (without substantiation)" You need to understand the difference between the clip planes defined by your view frustum, and custom clip planes defined (in legacy GL) via `glClipPlane`. The view frstum ones are left, right, bottom top, near and far. You can never get rid of left, right, top  and bottom planes, but it does not matter, because tanything outside of these 4 is outside of the viewport by the very nature of this. You can get rid of near and far, under certain circumstances.

Comment: And you can completely control all custom clip planes via `glClipControl`. They come with an enable bit and of cource can be enabled/disabled at evry time where `glEnable`/`glDisable` is allowed.